# Difference: Native and Non native Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to know about native and non native oracle sql queries. Are Distinct and Left outer join non native Oracle SQL? And if I use native oracle sql only in my query, will it imporve performance of my query? Since I am totally unaware of this and searching in google "what is native oracle sql" does not clear me, can anybody put a bit light on this? Any kind of explanation and/or supporting links are mostly appreciated.

Comment: I have never heard of this before...  Since `LEFT OUTER JOIN` was mentioned, perhaps they mean the difference between ANSI-89 and ANSI-92?

Comment: Not a clue.  Please show an example of these queries.

Comment: The comment sounds strange (to say the least). Can you quote it in full or provide a link?

Comment: Sounds like they want you to use Oracle's old `(+)` syntax for outer joins, despite [Oracle recommending you don't](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/queries006.htm#sthref2258). I'd ask for evidence that there is a performance difference; or look at timings and execution plans for the same query written both ways. No idea why they have a problem with `distinct` though..

Comment: I am not sure about the comment and I have confusion too on that. I have edited the question to make it more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's native Oracle or not-native, it's a case of implementing parts of an ANSI standard as mentioned above. Older Oracle at around version 7 only had joins in the where clause, the option was added later to have inner/outer/cross join before the where clause. Likewise Oracle was very forward thinking in adding analytic sql, xml support, pipelined queries, WITH clause and a load of other stuff before many vendors.

I don't think any vendor fully implements all of the current ANSI standards, I did see a compliance matrix on this a while back so will post a link if I can find it.

Here is one example - you can google for others but I doubt you'll find a complete list as there are very few / no people who are an expert on all relation db platforms:

http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/